# Should I always encapsulate an internal data structure entirely?

Tags: design, object-oriented, encapsulation

Please consider this class:

```
class ClassA{

    private Thing[] things; // stores data

    // stuff omitted

    public Thing[] getThings(){
        return things;
    }

}
```

This class exposes the array it uses to store data, to any client code interested.

I did this in an app I'm working on. I had a `ChordProgression` class that stores a sequence of `Chord`s (and does some other things). It had a `Chord[] getChords()` method that returned the array of chords. When the data structure had to change (from an array to an ArrayList), all client code broke.

This made me think - maybe the following approach is better:

```
class ClassA{

    private Thing[] things; // stores data

    // stuff omitted

    public Thing[] getThing(int index){
        return things[index];
    }

    public int getDataSize(){
        return things.length;
    }

    public void setThing(int index, Thing thing){
        things[index] = thing;
    }

}
```

Instead of exposing the data structure itself, **all of the operations offered by the data structure are now offered directly by the class enclosing it, using public methods that delegate to the data structure.**

When the data structure changes, only these methods have to change - but after they do, all client code still works.

**Note that collections more complex than arrays might require the enclosing class to implement even more than three methods just to access the internal data structure.**

---

Is this approach common? What do you think of this? What downsides does it have other? Is it reasonable to have the enclosing class implement at least three public methods just to delegate to the inner data structure?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Code like:

```
   public Thing[] getThings(){
        return things;
    }
```

Doesn't make much sense, since your access method is doing nothing but directly returning the internal data structure. You might as well just declare `Thing[] things` to be `public`. The idea behind an access method is to create an interface that insulates clients from internal changes and precludes them from manipulating the actual data structure except in discreet ways as allowed by the interface. As you discovered when all your client code broke, your access method didn't do that - it's just wasted code. I think a lot of programmers tend to write code like that because they learned somewhere that everything needs to be encapsulated with access methods - but that's for the reasons I explained. Doing it just to "follow form" when the access method isn't serving any purpose is just noise.

I would definitely recommend your proposed solution, which accomplishes some of the most important goals of encapsulation: Giving clients a robust, discreet interface that insulates them from the internal implementation details of your class, and doesn't allow them to touch the internal data structure expect in the ways that you decide are appropriate - "the law of least necessary privilege". If you look at the big popular OOP frameworks, such as the CLR, the STL, the VCL, the pattern you've proposed is widespread, for exactly that reason.

Should you **always** do that? Not necessarily. For example, if you have helper or friend classes that are essentially a component of your main worker class and are not "front facing", it's not necessary -  it's an overkill that's going to add a lot of unnecessary code. And in that case, I wouldn't use an access method at all - it's senseless, as explained. Just declare the data structure in a way that's scoped only to the main class that uses it - most languages support ways of doing that - `friend`, or declaring it in the same file as the main worker class, etc.

The only *downside* I can see in your proposal it that it's more work to code (and now you're going to have to re-code your consumer classes - but you have/had to do that anyway.) But that's not really a downside - you need to do it right, and sometimes that takes more work.

One of the things that makes a good programmer good is that they know when the extra work is worth it, and when it isn't. In the long run putting in the extra now will pay off with big dividends in the future - if not on this project, then on others. Learn to code the right way and use your head about it, not just robotically follow prescribed forms.

> Note that collections more complex than arrays might require the
>   enclosing class to implement even more than three methods just to
>   access the internal data structure.

If you're exposing an entire data structure through a containing class, IMO you need to think about why that class is encapsulated at all, if it's not simply to provide a safer interface - a "wrapper class". You're saying the containing class does not exist for that purpose - so perhaps there's something not right about your design. Consider breaking up your classes into more discreet modules and layering them.

A class should have one clear and discreet purpose, and provide an interface to support that functionality - no more. You may be trying to bundle things together that don't belong together. When you do that, things will be breaking every time you have to implement a change. The smaller and more discreet your classes are, the easier it is to change things around: **Think LEGO.**

Comment: Thanks for answering. A question: What about if the internal data structure has, maybe, 5 public methods - that all need to be featured by my class' public interface? For example, a Java ArrayList has the following methods: `get(index)`, `add()`, `size()`, `remove(index)`, and `remove(Object)`. Using the technique proposed, the class that contains this ArrayList must have five public methods just to delegate to the inner collection. And this class' purpose in the program is most likely not encapsulating this ArrayList, but rather doing something else. The ArrayList is just a detail. [...]

Comment: The inner data structure is just an ordinary member, that using the technique above - requires it's containing class to feature additional five public methods. In your opinion - is this reasonable? And also - is this common?

Comment: @Prog - _What about if the internal data structure has, maybe, 5 public methods..._ IMO if you find you need to wrap up an entire helper class inside your main class and expose it that way, you need to re-think that design -your public class is doing too much an/or not presenting the appropriate interface. A class should have a very discreet and clearly defined role, and its interface should support that role and only that role. Think about breaking up and layering your classes. A class should not be a "kitchen sink" that contains all sorts of objects in the name of encapsulation.

Comment: If you're exposing an entire data structure through a wrapper class, IMO you need to think about why that class is encapsulated at all if it's not simply to provide a safer interface. You're saying the containing  class does not exist for that purpose - so there's something not right about this design.

Comment: I disagree. Looking at the class interface, nowhere does it specify that you're returning the internal data structure. You can get at whatever is in the class as an array, but if I'm returning `collectionType.ToArray()` that's still valid. I see no issue with returning a collection type for read-only tasks, libraries and language features will work better with them than your type without additional effort, and you lose nothing. Read-only is the keyword, though--you're offering a view, not the internal state.

Comment: @Phoshi - _Read-only is the keyword_ - I can agree with that. But the OP is not talking about read-only. for example `remove` is not read only. My understanding is the OP wants to make everything public - like in the original code before the proposed change `public Thing[] getThings(){return things;}` That's what I don't like.

Comment: Let me see if I understand what you're saying. You're saying that the technique I proposed is good, but only when implemented in classes *that the reason for their existence is to wrap data structures*. For example: let's say I have a class that holds data in an array - and it wants to expose this data to the world. But as we said, having `Thing[] getData()` is problematic, since the moment I want to change e.g. from an array to a List, client code breaks. So we can use the technique I proposed. (Continuing in next comment..)

Comment: I.e. creating a thin wrapper around the collection to not expose it's concrete type. But this technique *won't be implemented in the said class that contains the array* - instead, *I would create another class `DataWrapper` that implements this technique.* The original class can than encpasulate a `DataWrapper` and have a method `DataWrapper getData()`, that the client can use - without the original class being forced to implement 5 additional methods just to wrap the collection (these methods will be implemented by `DataWrapper`). Is my understanding correct?

Comment: _Let me see if I understand what you're saying..._ - not exactly. I think the approach you suggested is the right one. Period. I'm questioning a different aspect: Why does your design compel you to provide an interface to **all the functionality** of  `things` - that is the job of a wrapper class, but you aren't talking about a wrapper class. So I personally smell "bundling" in your overall design: If you need to expose all the functionality, you're **probably** trying to do too much in your worker class and should consider trying to make things more modular and layered: **Think Lego.** :)

Comment: *"You're probably trying to do too much in your worker class and should consider trying to make things more modular..."* - I tried to make things more modular and layered by making a wrapper class - let's call it `DataWrapper` - that wraps the collection and provides an interface to access it. And then instead of `SomeClass` - that exists to serve some functionality - serving also as the wrapper class (which is what I described in my question), there's a different class that serves as a wrapper class, that exists in order to not expose the wrapped collection's concrete type. [...]

Comment: And than the wrapper class is composed with the 'worker class' (`SomeClass`), and is exposed by `SomeClass`'s public method. I think this is rather modular and 'single responsibility'. I'm trying understand your criticism to this design, not really I understand what you mean.

Comment: The only difference between the idea I described in my original question, and the newer thing, is that in the original question, `SomeClass` had two roles: serving some functionality, and also wrapping a data structure. With the new thing, `SomeClass` has one role - serving some functionality, and `DataWrapper` has the other role - wrapping the collection. Instead of inflating `SomeClass`'s interface with 'collection-wrapping' methods, these methods are in `DataWrapper`, and `DataWrapper` is composed with `SomeClass`. Am I more clear now? If so, do you still have criticism to this?

Comment: @Prog: _do you still have criticism to this_ - That sounds much better.

Answer (score 2):

**You asked:** Should I always encapsulate an internal data structure entirely?

**Brief Answer:** Yes, most of the time but not *always*.

**Long Answer:** I think that classes follow into following categories:

1. Classes that encapsulate simple data. Example: 2D point. It's easy to create public functions that provide the ability to get/set the X and Y coordinates but you can hide the internal data easily without too much trouble. For such classes, exposing the internal data structure details is uncalled for.
2. Container classes that encapsulate collections. STL has the classic container classes. I consider `std::string` and `std::wstring` among those too. They provide a rich interface to deal with the abstractions but `std::vector`, `std::string`, and `std::wstring` also provide the ability to get access to the raw data. I wouldn't be hasty to call them poorly designed classes. I don't know the justification for these classes exposing their raw data. However, I have, in my work, found it necessary to expose the raw data when dealing with millions of mesh nodes and data on those mesh nodes for performance reasons.

   The important thing about exposing the internal structure of a class is that you have to think long and hard before giving it a green signal. If the interface is internal to a project, it will be expensive to change it in the future but not impossible. If the interface is external to the project (such as when you are developing a library that will be used by other application developers), it may be impossible to change the interface without losing your clients.
3. Classes that are mostly functional in nature. Examples: `std::istream`, `std::ostream`, iterators of the STL containers. It's outright foolish to expose the internal details of these classes.
4. Hybrid classes. These are classes that encapsulate some data structure but also provide algorithmic functionality. Personally, I think these are a result of poorly thought design. However, if you find them, you have to decide whether it makes sense to expose their internal data on a case by case basis.

**In conclusion:** The only time I have found it necessary to expose the internal data structure of a class is when it became a performance bottleneck.

Comment: I think the most important reason that STL exposes their internal data is compatibility with all the functions that expect pointers, which are a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should use interfaces for those things. Wouldn't help in your case, since Java's array don't implement those interfaces, but you should do it from now on:

```
class ClassA{

    public ClassA(){
        things = new ArrayList<Thing>();
    }

    private List<Thing> things; // stores data

    // stuff omitted

    public List<Thing> getThings(){
        return things;
    }

}
```

That way you can change `ArrayList` to `LinkedList` or anything else, and you won't break any code since all Java collections(beside arrays) that have (pseudo?) random access will probably implement `List`.

You can also use `Collection`, that offer less methods than `List` but can support collections without random access, or `Iterable` that can even support streams but doesn't offer much in term of access methods...

Comment: -1 - poor compromise and not particularly safe IMO: You are exposing the internal data structure to the client, just masking it and hoping for the best because "Java collections... will **probably** implement List." If your solution was truly polymorphic/inheritance based - that all collections invariably implement `List` as derived classes, it would make more sense, but just "hoping for the best" is not a good idea. "A good programmer looks both ways on a one way street".

Comment: @Vector Yes, I'm assuming future Java collections will implement `List`(or `Collection`, or at least `Iterable`). That's the whole point of these interfaces, and it's a shame that Java Arrays don't implement them, but they are official interface for collections in Java so it's not that far fetched to assume any Java collection will implement them - unless that collection is older than `List`, and in that case it's very easy to wrap it with [AbstractList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html).

Comment: You're saying that your assumption is virtually guaranteed to hold true, so OK - I'm will remove the down-vote (when I'm allowed to ) because you were decent enough to explain, and I'm not a Java guy except by osmosis. Still, I don't  support this idea of exposing the internal data structure, regardless of how it's done, and you haven't directly answered the OP's question, which is really about encapsulation. i.e. limiting access to the internal data structure.

Comment: @Vector Yes, users can cast the `List` into `ArrayList`, but it's not like the implementation can be 100% protected - you can always use reflection to access private fields. Doing so is frowned upon, but casting is also frowned upon(not as much though). The point of encapsulation is not prevent malicious hacking - rather, it's to prevent the users from depending on implementation details you might want to change. Using the `List` interface does exactly that - users of the class can depend on the `List` interface instead of the concrete `ArrayList` class that might change.

Comment: _you can always use reflection to access private fields_ certainly-if someone wants to write bad code and subvert a design, they can do so. _rather, it's to prevent the users..._ - that's **one** reason for encapsulation. Another is to ensure the integrity and consistency of the internal state of your class. The problem is not "malicious hacking", but poor organization that leads to nasty bugs. "Law of least necessary privilege"-give the consumer of your class only what's mandatory - no more. If it's mandatory that you make an entire internal data structure public, you've got a design problem.

Comment: You are not making the **entire** internal data structure public - only the `List` interface of it. The asker is already giving free access to read and modify the internal data structure, and `List` doesn't provide any more access than that. I've suggested to `return` the data structure directly because that's the simplest way to do it, but that doesn't mean the internal data structure is exposed. If in the feature the internal data structure to something completely different - say querying the data from a web service - you could still override `AbstractList` and return a `List` object.

Comment: _The asker is already giving free access to read and modify the internal data structure_ - from the continuation _Note that collections more complex..._ it appears so. And so in the comments I remarked that indicates a design problem. If you're exposing an entire data structure through a wrapper class, you need to think about why that class is encapsulated at all if it's not simply to provide a safer interface. But the question says the the main class does not exist for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning the raw data directly, try something like this

```
class ClassA {
  private Things[] things;
  ...
  public Things[] asArray() { return things; }
  public List<Thing> asList() { ... }
  ...
}
```

So, you are essentially providing a custom collection that presents whatever face to the world is desired. In your new implementation then,

```
class ClassA {
  private List<Thing> things;
  ...
  public Things[] asArray() { return things.asArray(); }
  public List<Thing> asList() { return things; }
  ...
}
```

Now you have the proper encapsulation, hide the implementation details, and provide backwards compatibility (at a cost).

Comment: Clever idea for backwards compatability. But: _Now you have the proper encapsulation, hide the implementation details_ - not really. Clients still have to deal with the nuances of `List`. Access methods that simply return data members, even with a cast to make things more robust, isn't really good encapsulation IMO. The worker class should be handling all that, not the client. The "dumber" a client has to be, the more robust it will be. As an aside, I'm not sure you answered the question...

Comment: @Vector - you are correct. The data structure returned is still mutable and side-effects will kill the information hiding.

Comment: _The data structure returned is still mutable and side-effects will kill the information hiding_ - yes,that too - it's dangerous. I was simply thinking in terms of what is required from the client, which was the focus of the question.

Comment: @BobDalgleish: why not return a copy of the original collection?

Comment: @Giorgio - you can always return a copy. However, if that was not in the original agreement, the client may assume they are free to make changes to the data and that those changes will be retained.

Comment: @BobDalgleish: Unless there are good performance reasons, I would consider returning a reference to internal data structures to allow its users to change them as a very bad design decision. The internal state of an object should only be changed through appropriate public methods.

Comment: @Giorgio - I would agree with you. However, the original question had the implication that the data structure was not at all private. The other answers do a lot to answer the substantial portion of the question.

Answer (score -2):

This is pretty common to hide your internal data structure from outside world. Sometime it is overkill specially in DTO. I recommend this for domain model. If at all its required to expose, return the immutable copy. Along with this i suggest creating an interface having these methods like get , set , remove etc.

Comment: this doesn't seem to offer anything substantial over 3 prior answers