# "Collection Wrapper" pattern - is this common?

Tags: design, object-oriented, collections

[A different question of mine](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/241179/should-i-always-encapsulate-an-internal-data-structure-entirely) had to do with encapsulating member data structures inside classes. In order to understand *this* question better please read *that* question and look at the approach discussed.

One of the guys who answered that question said that the approach is good, but if I understood him correctly - he said that there should be a class existing just for the purpose of wrapping the collection, instead of an ordinary class offering a number of public methods just to access the member collection.

For example, instead of this:

```
class SomeClass{

    // downright exposing the concrete collection.        

    Things[] someCollection;

   // other stuff omitted

    Thing[] getCollection(){return someCollection;}

}
```

Or this:

```
class SomeClass{

    // encapsulating the collection, but inflating the class' public interface.

    Thing[] someCollection;

    // class functionality omitted.

    public Thing getThing(int index){
        return someCollection[index];
    }

    public int getSize(){
        return someCollection.length;
    }

    public void setThing(int index, Thing thing){
        someCollection[index] = thing;
    }

    public void removeThing(int index){
        someCollection[index] = null;
    }

}
```

We'll have this:

```
// encapsulating the collection - in a different class, dedicated to this.

class SomeClass{
    CollectionWrapper someCollection;

    CollectionWrapper  getCollection(){return someCollection;}
}

class CollectionWrapper{

    Thing[] someCollection;

    public Thing getThing(int index){
        return someCollection[index];
    }

    public int getSize(){
        return someCollection.length;
    }

    public void setThing(int index, Thing thing){
        someCollection[index] = thing;
    }

    public void removeThing(int index){
        someCollection[index] = null;
    }

}
```

This way, the inner data structure in `SomeClass` can change without affecting client code, and without forcing `SomeClass` to offer a lot of public methods just to access the inner collection. `CollectionWrapper` does this instead.

E.g. if the collection changes from an array to a `List`, the internal implementation of `CollectionWrapper` changes, but client code stays the same.

Also, the `CollectionWrapper` can hide certain things from the client code - from example, it can disallow mutation to the collection by not having the methods `setThing` and `removeThing`.

**This approach to decoupling client code from the concrete data structure seems IMHO pretty good.**

Is this approach common? What are it's downfalls? Is this used in practice?

Comment: I can't say I've ever really come across the need in developing any software to change a list into an array.  The other way around, sure, but this has just led to my operating principle being "just use a list, you might need its features later".  Don't know if other people feel the same way, though...

Comment: Why bloat your class with methods that regurgitate basic collection behavior? Why not provide a collection property that provides the type of access you would like to give to your collection?  Ex: public IEnumerable<T> Items {get{};}  //read only

Comment: Assuming your example is non-trivial, it seems like simple composition to me.

Comment: @CheckRaise What I'm trying to do, is not expose the collection - because I don't want the client code to break when the collection changes say from a List to a Set. If I just allow the client code to do `class.getCollection()` it'll break when the type of the collection changes. So the idea is to make a thin layer around it ("CollectionWrapper"), so when the type of collection changes, only the wrapper has to change, but not the code using the collection (i.e. using the wrapper). Is what I'm saying clear?

Comment: When a client uses `SomeClass::getCollection()`, they are exposed to `CollectionWrapper`. Their code will start using interface provided by `CollectionWrapper`. The dependency on the container type shifts from `SomeClass` to `CollectionWrapper`. It is not eliminated. I am not sure what the gains are.

Comment: @RSahu The idea is that a data structure used by a class is likely to change. E.g. A class might use a List, and later on change to a Set. If the clients of the class depended directly on the collection (i.e. `getCollection' is '{return actualCollec;}`), client code will break. Wrapping the collection in a class with a generic interface, means changes to the collection are hidden in that class. The wrapper's interface stays the same no matter what the collection inside the wrapper is. Client code relies on the generic interface of the wrapper, and doesn't break when the collection changes.

Comment: Why aren't you just implementing `Collection` and then passing that around? Which would allow it to work with all of the existing collection utilities rather than forcing the client to peak into the abstraction to do standard things?

Comment: @RSahu And to address what you said: *"The dependency on the container type shifts from SomeClass to CollectionWrapper... I am not sure what the gains are."* `SomeClass` already takes care of some responsibility in the system. Without `CollectionWrapper`, `SomeClass` itself would have to wrap the inner collection (i.e. have a number of public methods such as `get(int i)`). `CollectionWrapper` is simply meant to take care of that instead of bloating `SomeClass` interface with such methods. Am I clearer?

Comment: @MichaelT Two things. 1- Not sure what you meant by *"forcing the client to peak into the abstraction"* - but the client doesn't need to do anything special. Only use the `CollectionWrapper` interface, i.e. `get()`, `add()` etc. 2- Again not sure what you meant. If you mean to implement a new `Collection` interface - that would mean I need to make wrappers for all the existing collections, that implement that interface. If you meant to implement the Java `Collection` interface - actually that's a better idea I suppose, except for the flaw that arrays don't implement this interface.

Comment: @Jules: In many frameworks, copying e.g. 1,000 consecutive items from one array to another may be done in significantly less than half the time it would take to process 1,000 items individually.  Thus, if one has two array-backed collections which know nothing about each other, exporting 1,000 items from the first to an array, and then having the second copy 1,000 items from that array, may be much faster than copying 1,000 items one at a time.  Note that it the speed-up doesn't require that either collection hold its data using a single array; even if a collection used...

Comment: ...e.g. a multitude of 256-item arrays to hold its contents, copying five batches of items to or from a 1,000-item temporary array would still likely be much faster than having to use 1,000 separate operations.

Comment: @supercat agreed; performance is the only consideration that I can think of in favour of arrays... but it is unusual in my experience that this degree of performance is required.  The overhead in processing 1,000 items from a list iterator versus an array is perhaps in the order of a million processor cycles, which is trivial for most applications.  My experience is that the time taken by the actual processing to be performed on the items usually dwarfs this amount of time.  And using collections, which can be easily wrapped, e.g. with an immutable wrapper, may avoid the requirement to copy.

Comment: @Jules: IMHO, one of the major weaknesses which .NET still has not addressed in its collections is that none of the collection interfaces include a method to request an `IEnumerable<T>` which will always encapsulate the sequence of items the collection holds at the time of the request. An immutable collection could simply return a reference to itself; a mutable collection could copy itself to a new immutable collection.  Such a feature would allow many copy operations to be safely elided. Unfortunately, without such a feature, the only way to encapsulate the sequence in an `IEnumerable<T>`....

Comment: ...whose particular type one doesn't recognize as promising immutability is to make a copy of it.  Note that while many instances of `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` are immutable, the type offers no means by which an instance can indicate whether it's actually immutable or not.  If code which needs an immutable sequence receives e.g. the return from `Enumerable.Range(1,1000000)`, it shouldn't need to make a copy, but there is at present no way for the `Enumerable.Range` return to let it know that, especially if wrapped in a `ReadOnlyCollection<int>`.

Answer (score 6):

You are implementing a restricted set of the [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) interface, without actually giving it something that you can work with.

> E.g. if the collection changes from an array to a List, the internal 
>   implementation of CollectionWrapper changes, but client code stays the same.

This is *exactly* what the `Collection` interface is intended to do.  If you pass back a Collection, that is all the client can work from.

> Also, the CollectionWrapper can hide certain things from the client code - from example, it can disallow mutation to the collection by not having the methods setThing and removeThing.

In Java, this is known as an Unmodifiable Collection, and the [Collections utility](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableCollection%28java.util.Collection%29) has just such a method to convert a modifiable collection to an unmodifiable one.

By making the restricted wrapper you are also giving up things such as [sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) and [iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#iterator%28%29) which come in *very* handy from time to time.  This means code such as:

```
for(Thing t : someCollection) {
    ....
}
```

won't work.  Instead, the code would need to be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < someCollection.size(); i++) {
    Thing t = someCollection.get(i);
    ....
}
```

While that is perfectly acceptable code, it also means you are failing to take advantage of the language to allow the client to write code faster (programmer time is expensive).

The way you decouple the implementation is to use an interface, preferably one that already exists in the language framework so that other things that use that same interface can use your code without jumping through additional hoops.

---

Just a note:

> What I'm trying to do, is not expose the collection - because I don't want the client code to break when the collection changes say from a List to a Set. If I just allow the client code to do `class.getCollection()` it'll break when the type of the collection changes. So the idea is to make a thin layer around it ("CollectionWrapper"), so when the type of collection changes, only the wrapper has to change, but not the code using the collection (i.e. using the wrapper). Is what I'm saying clear?

If the collection is only given as a Collection interface, it won't break.  *However*, I must point out that the public methods that you are presenting with this class, namely `public Thing getThing(int index)`, `public void setThing(int index, Thing thing)`, and `public void removeThing(int index)` would preclude the implementation from changing from a List to a Set, because Sets have no concept of indexes and these methods would need to change.

Comment: I will sometimes return an immutable collection, seems to be the quickest way to implement the idea of "iterate over objects in some other object." I also like the idea of the "collection wrapper" being the collection interface itself: it is already written and tons of code in the real world already uses it.

Answer (score 1):

You're describing the [Encapsulated Collection](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/EncapsulatedCollection.html) pattern. I like this pattern a lot; it's especially appropriate to domain-driven design.

The advantage you describe - being able to change the internal representation of the collection - is a good one. But I think the bigger advantage is restricting clients' ability to modify or break the underlying collection.

For example, consider a "commenting" feature of a social network, with the requirement that you can't delete comments after they've been posted. If you expose the `List<Comment>` as a property, it's easy for clients of your class to call the list's `Remove` method without realising they weren't supposed to.

If, instead, you use a `Comments` class with a private `List<Comment>` and no `Remove` method, it's now impossible to break the invariant.

You also end up with a richer domain model, which is better equipped to deal with new features. (A collection of domain objects is often a new domain concept that your model is missing.) Imagine that the requirement's changed and now it's possible to delete comments, but the deletion has to be recorded in an audit trail. It's easy to implement this behaviour in a new `Delete` method on your `Comments` class - it would have been much more complicated to override the pre-existing `Remove` method on the `List`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right.

I have developed several custom collections in diferent programming languages, and, sometimes, I applied the pattern. I also check that other developers also applied.

It seems that it depends on what the developer wants to achieve, sometimes, the collection is access directly, sometimes, using the pattern.

Visual controls with several items like "Treeview", "Listview", "Gridview" use a lot of this technique.

Answer (score 0):

You said,

> What I'm trying to do, is not expose the collection - because I don't want the client code to break when the collection changes say from a List to a Set.

I have concerns about that requirement -- whether perceived or real.

The abstractions represented by those standard containers are so distinct and different, I find it hard that you will be able to substitute one for another in your interface. If `SomeClass` provides an interface that is more appropriate for a `Set`, you have to honor that interface regardless of how you implement the `Set`. The same logic applies for `List` too. In that sense, you don't have to expose `ContainerWrapper` or `Container` at all. They are implementation details of `SomeClass`. You could use [pimpl pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) to completely hide the container.

Perhaps `SomeClass` is a container of objects with additional meaning.

For example, in a CAD program, an Assembly consists of sub-components that can be Parts or sub-Assemblies. However, that is not sufficient to capture the relationship between an Assembly and one of its sub-components. The location and orientation of the sub-component in the Assembly is the key piece of data that makes this particular container-contained relationship work. For this case, whether you store the collection of `Pair<sub-component, transform>` as a List or a Set is of very little importance in the interface of Assembly. You need to be able to query the Assembly for its sub-components and given a sub-component, you need to be able to query the Assembly for the transform of the sub-component in the Assembly.

Another example: A Canvas and its contained objects in a 2D painting program or an SVG program. Here again, the container-contained relationship has to be created using the 2D position of the contained objects plus a depth to
in order to arrange them in layers. Here also, you can use a Set or a List to hold the contained objects.

In conclusion, I am asking you to dig deeper to determine the kind of relationship `SomeClass` has with its contained objects. Is it a matter of simple containment or is there more to the relationship? If there is more to the relationship, how would you expose the relationship that is divorced from a List or a Set.

In both the examples I presented, a List makes more sense to me. I can't say what makes more sense for `SomeClass`.